# Why does this code work in one scenario while it won't in another?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm manually filling up some categorical labels in a column which is `is_holiday`. There are rows that have only the first observation with the correct label, the rest are 0 and I'm filling these zeros:

```py
# Before filling
print(main_data.loc["25 December, 2012"].is_holiday)

date_time
2012-12-25 00:00:00    3
2012-12-25 01:00:00    0
2012-12-25 02:00:00    0
2012-12-25 03:00:00    0
.
.
.
2012-12-25 19:00:00    0
2012-12-25 20:00:00    0
2012-12-25 21:00:00    0
2012-12-25 22:00:00    0
2012-12-25 23:00:00    0
Name: is_holiday, dtype: int64

# Manually fill
for row in range(len(main_data.loc["2012"])):
    if main_data.Month[row] == 12 and main_data.Day[row] == 25:
        if main_data.is_holiday[row] == 0:
            main_data.is_holiday[row] = 3  # 3 is label for Xmas

# After filling
print(main_data.loc["25 December, 2012"].is_holiday)
2012-12-25 00:00:00    3
2012-12-25 01:00:00    3
2012-12-25 02:00:00    3
2012-12-25 03:00:00    3
.
.
.
2012-12-25 19:00:00    3
2012-12-25 20:00:00    3
2012-12-25 21:00:00    3
2012-12-25 22:00:00    3
2012-12-25 23:00:00    3
Name: is_holiday, dtype: int64
```

However, if I execute the same code for another year, say 2013, the values remain the same. I tried modifying the code including minor changes but the holiday labels won't change:

```py
# Before filling
print(main_data.loc["25 December, 2013"].is_holiday)

date_time
2013-12-25 00:00:00    3
2013-12-25 01:00:00    0
2013-12-25 02:00:00    0
2013-12-25 03:00:00    0
.
.
.
2013-12-25 19:00:00    0
2013-12-25 20:00:00    0
2013-12-25 21:00:00    0
2013-12-25 22:00:00    0
2013-12-25 23:00:00    0
Name: is_holiday, dtype: int64

# Manually fill
for row_2 in range(len(main_data.loc["2013"])):
    if main_data.Month[row_2] == 12 and main_data.Day[row_2] == 25:
        if main_data.is_holiday[row_2] == 0:
            main_data.is_holiday[row_2] = 3  # 3 is label for Xmas

# After filling
print(main_data.loc["25 December, 2013"].is_holiday)
2013-12-25 00:00:00    3
2013-12-25 01:00:00    0
2013-12-25 02:00:00    0
2013-12-25 03:00:00    0
.
.
.
2013-12-25 19:00:00    0
2013-12-25 20:00:00    0
2013-12-25 21:00:00    0
2013-12-25 22:00:00    0
2013-12-25 23:00:00    0
Name: is_holiday, dtype: int64
```

What am I missing here? I did not expect this to happen. It works as expected for some holidays while it won't for others. **Please do keep in mind that `Month` and `Day` are separate columns that I have engineered in `main_data`.**

Edit: I'm welcome to better methods for achieving this.

Comment: What's the index in your main data frame

Comment: It's the datetime stamps with the column name `date_time`.

Comment: Use [DataFrame.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or  [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to update values based on conditions.

Comment: The index doesn't have a column name, I don't get it. What's your index?

Comment: @ifly6 The name itself is `date_time` and includes timestamps from 2012-10-02 to 2017-05-17.

Comment: @SmileyProd Can you show an example?

Comment: I'm not sure how you use `.loc` then, because afaik it doesn't match on such data. `np.where(cond, if_true, if_false)` in which all are series with the same length. The `cond` is the same format as what you would use for a subsetting command to get what you wnat.

Comment: Well `.loc ` worked for New Year 2013. Before I set the condition in `[]` without using `.loc` and it worked the same way as `.loc`. So I Only made the code more readable by inserting `.loc`. But I'll try using `.where`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming the date is the index i would simply do:

```
df.loc[(df.index.day == 25) & (df.index.month ==12),['is_holiday']] = 3
```

full code with example:

```
#init data
df = pd.DataFrame(          \    
[['2012-12-25 19:00:00',0,0], \
['2012-12-25 20:00:00',0,0],  \
['2012-12-26 19:00:00',0,0],  \
['2012-12-26 20:00:00',0,0],  \
['2013-01-25 19:00:00',0,0],  \
['2013-01-25 20:00:00',0,0],  \
['2013-12-25 19:00:00',0,0],  \
['2013-12-25 20:00:00',0,0]])

#set index
df.columns = ['date','is_holiday','some_value']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')

#do the search
df.loc[(df.index.day == 25) & (df.index.month ==12),['is_holiday']] = 3
print(df)
```

result:

```
                     is_holiday  value
date                                  
2012-12-25 19:00:00  3           0    
2012-12-25 20:00:00  3           0    
2012-12-26 19:00:00  0           0    
2012-12-26 20:00:00  0           0    
2013-01-25 19:00:00  0           0    
2013-01-25 20:00:00  0           0    
2013-12-25 19:00:00  3           0    
2013-12-25 20:00:00  3           0
```

some useful links:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-date-components

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

[Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Worked lightning fast.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has some nice builtin functions for this kind of task. So you could just do

```py
import numpy as np
main_data.is_holiday.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
main_data.is_holiday.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

should do it.

EDIT:

To apply the fill to the holidays only:

```py
main_data['is_holiday'] = main_data.is_holiday.resample('D').max()
main_data.is_holiday.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

The first line replaces the `is_holiday` column with the maximum value for that day for the midnight timestamp, which is assumed to be present. The second line fills the other rows, which should by now have a NaN.

Comment: But for days that had no holidays the label remains 0. Won't your code disturb those correct zeros?

Comment: Ah, I see. True. Hold on.

Comment: Wow. That is good. Can you explain more in detail the first line of code? What does resample with 'D' do and how does lambda work here?

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error: `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).`

Comment: Ok, I do not know what is up. I will try once more.

Comment: Thats fine. The logic is workable but only getting index error. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually doing

```
for row in range(len(main_data.loc["2012"]))
#let's says len(main_data.loc["2012"]) = 100
```

You select line 0 to 100 and replace 0 by 3.

```
for row_2 in range(len(main_data.loc["2013"]))
#let's says len(main_data.loc["2013"]) = 50
```

You select line 0 to 50 and replace 0 by 3.

You are doing this in you'r main data set so both code will replace first line of the data set.

You can solve it using something like (pseudo code):

```
for row in np.where(years=2013,month==12)
```

Comment: But am I not being specific in mentioning the years? I thought specifying years should run the operations separately and not for the whole dataframe as such.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comment you can use DataFrame.where or np.where to do the assignments but I think the best in your case is DataFrame.where:

```
mask = (main_data.date_time.dt.year == 2012) & (main_data.Month == 12) & (main_data.Day == 25)
main_data[mask].is_holiday = main_data[mask]\
                                    .is_holiday\
                                    .where(~(main_data[mask].is_holiday == 0)), 3)
```

2. numpy.where

```
main_data[mask].is_holiday = np.where(main_data[mask].is_holiday == 0, 3,\
                                             main_data[mask].is_holiday)
```